# how to copy value from one text input to array/multiple text input

Tags: javascript

how to copy value from one text input to array text input

```
<script>
function sync()
{
  var n1 = document.getElementById('n1');
  var n2 = document.getElementById('n2');
  n2.value = n1.value;
}
</script>
<input type="text" name="n1" id="n1" onkeyup="sync()"><br />
<input type="text" name="n2[]" id="n2"/><br />
<input type="text" name="n2[]" id="n2"/><br />
<input type="text" name="n2[]" id="n2"/><br />
<input type="text" name="n2[]" id="n2"/><br />
<input type="text" name="n2[]" id="n2"/><br />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I pointed out in the comments `id` attribute should be unique in a page, ie there should be only one element with an id. In your case you have many elements with id `n2`

If I understand the requirement, you want to copy the value of `n1` to all `n2` elements. You can use the [getElementsByName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementsByName) to achieve this

```
function sync() {
    var n1 = document.getElementById('n1');
    var n2s = document.getElementsByName('n2[]');
    for(var i=0; i<n2s.length;i++){
        n2s[i].value = n1.value;
    }
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XuXhu/)

Answer (score 0):

@Arun has already explained how to achieve what you want through a `for` loop and using `id` correctly. I would just like to add to his answer and clear up any confusion that you might have.

When you duplicate `name`s you're creating an Array. Duplicating `id`s is just plain wrong as they are **identifier**(s) and have to be *unique*.

Note that there's NO getElement(**s**)ById() function. It's `getElementByID()` as it's supposed to return the *one single* element that's associated with this identifier.

Also note that you didn't receive any Javascript errors there and `getElementById()` simply returned the **first** text input associated with id `n2`.